# Cannot re-submit Skype channel for review

Tags: botframework

When I try to re-submit my Skype channel Web App bot for review I got an error on the Microsoft Azure portal. "CorrelationID: |OgnX4.RKq/h.ee42bd69_"

The value after the colon always change, the above is only an example.

Comment: Please post an issue on the BotBuilder GitHub repository, and provide your BotHandle and MicrosoftAppId: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new

Comment: This was originated talking on support chat, who asked me to open this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/435b5cd7-d618-4c8f-aad6-f77c02be956a/cannot-resubmit-skype-channel-for-review?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: I will open an issue on GitHub, where can I find my BotHandle?

Comment: Bot Handle is in the bot settings on the Azure portal.